# Can we ask questions about open-source games?

Tags: discussion

There are plenty of free and open-source games out there, for various platforms. However, I notice no one ever asks about them.

For example, take [AssaultCube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AssaultCube). It's a semi-popular open-source game, however, there are no questions about it, or any similar open-source game (that I've heard of) anywhere to be found.

Are questions about games like these off-topic, or are there no questions simply because the game doesn't get enough attention?

Comment: Theres many many games with no questions, go for it! :)

Comment: [Untrusted](https://alexnisnevich.github.io/untrusted/), an open-source game [licensed under CC-BY-NC-SA 3.0](https://github.com/AlexNisnevich/untrusted), has [16 questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untrusted) at the time of this posting.

Comment: [NetHack](http://www.nethack.org) is open source ([with many, many available patches](https://bilious.alt.org) and [forks](https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Variant)), and it has [158 questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nethack) so far.

Comment: [tag:battle-for-wesnoth] is an open source game and it has 9 existing questions.

Comment: You'd think all JRPGs were against the rules if we were basing it off of number of questions. I am pretty sure there are 5-10 of us on here to ask and answer all of them?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's no reason you can't ask questions about these sorts of games - they're perfectly on topic here. Like you said, however, the games might not be as well known as other games, so that's likely why you've seen few questions about them.

So, please do ask questions about them here, as they are on topic, and welcomed. :)

Comment: Thanks! Also, within the modding rules for other games, would it be OK to ask about how to mod these games (since most of them come with some built-in editor?)

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI I'd assume that probably depends on whether or not they *do* come with an editor. If they do, then I think those would be allowed, otherwise it would be off-topic.

Answer (score -5):

actually the games which are popular among people they know that if I ask a question someone will eventually answer it. for unpopular games (which are not well known or not advertised) people asking the question loose the hope (they think the post won't be answered) so people generally don't tend to ask questions regarding *"open-sourced"* games.

By generally you can ask question about any game (but not all of them are answered as i said earlier).

Comment: 'Open Source' isn't a popularity thing, it simply means that the game code is available for download publicly, so you can write mods, change things you don't like about the game, add levels/story/characters/whatever, or use it as a base for your own game (usually with the copyright terms stating that you use the same open-source policy).